# Allow SSL man-in-the-middle with firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl

I want to log everything firefox send to a server, down to every exact byte so I can reproduce it in a python client. So my idea was to make a quick and dirty hack :

- run a `openssl s_server`,
- make firefox connect to localhost by adding a line in my `/etc/hosts`.

This shouldn't have taken more than 5 seconds to setup, run, remove.

My issue is on the firefox side. First, it doesn't allow me to add a security exception. Second, even when I add one in *[about:preferences#advanced](http://about:preferences#advances) > Certificates > View certificates > Servers*, it changes nothing and show me the error `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER` anyway.

How do I make firefox ignore the certificate error?
Is there another quick and easy way to log SSL traffic?

Comment: Try Charles Proxy, free trial.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found was to use firefox's `SSLKEYLOGFILE` environment variable and configure wireshark to use this file to decrypt the HTTP requests.

This is all explained here:
https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/

However, care must be taken to clear the cache for the website so that firefox actually send the requests and don't use the cached result.